# Accessing password from field in a secure way

Tags: android, security, passwords

```
String basicAuth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString( (emailText.getText().toString() + ":" + passwordText.getText().toString()).getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

How to handle this. I need to make basic authentication token. When the password is typed in, you can find the password in the debugger in EditText passwordText. Will that show in a memory dump? Not only that what about getText().toString() will the string stay in the memory for some time? I know you can easily find the token but that's not the point, the point is no one to be able to find out your password. What should I do?

Answer (score -1):

This what I am using. AES encryption for storing sensitive

```
package com.myapp.utilities;

import android.content.Context;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Base64;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class Security {
    private static final String TAG = Security.class.getSimpleName();

    private Cipher cipher;
    private SecretKeySpec key;
    private AlgorithmParameterSpec spec;

    public Security(Context context) throws Exception {
        // hash password with SHA-256 and crop the output to 128-bit for key
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

        String secret = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
//        secret = "asjldknfajlsdbc DCNJANSDKJNACSDCnmcnc ###";

        digest.update(secret.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        byte[] keyBytes = new byte[32];
        System.arraycopy(digest.digest(), 0, keyBytes, 0, keyBytes.length);

        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
        key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
        spec = getIV();
    }

    public AlgorithmParameterSpec getIV(){
        byte[] iv = {
                (byte) 0x8E, 0x12, 0x39, (byte) 0x9C, 0x07, 0x72, 0x6F, 0x5A,
                (byte) 0x8E, 0x12, 0x39, (byte) 0x9C, 0x07, 0x72, 0x6F, 0x5A
        };
        IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec;
        ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

        return ivParameterSpec;
    }

    public String encrypt(String plainText) throws Exception{
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(plainText)) {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, spec);
            return new String(Base64.encode(cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8")), Base64.DEFAULT), "UTF-8");
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String decrypt(String cryptedText) throws Exception {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(cryptedText)) {
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, spec);
            return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(cryptedText, Base64.DEFAULT)), "UTF-8");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And to the question about memory dump, that is still within the phone and it has not leaked outside your phone. You will be sending encrypted data over network rather than simple data. Obviously, keylogger or similar can easily detect all this, but how many will be doing it? And who will be the one who will be encrypting strings on fly while typing password?